# What services do you use to research European stock markets?

Tags: investing, stock-exchanges, stocks

I would like to know what are the best services to research stocks on the different European stock markets, I would like to cover all EU member states, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with your resources or work situation, but the Bloomberg Terminal is best in breed for market research/pricing/data on pretty much any security.  Works great for European equities.  The downside: it runs about $1,500 a month if you have to pay for one on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no access to a Bloomberg Terminal :) If you know what is the next best thing, but a littlebit cheaper please, let me know! Thanks for the recommendation anyway

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/solutions/asset-management/) and [Reuters](http://financial.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/tools-applications/trading-investment-tools/eikon-trading-software/market-analysis-content-features.html), I would recommend [WorldCap](http://worldcap.org), which is not a terminal but a mobile solution to research stocks in the US, Europe and Asia. While Bloomberg and Reuters run about $20,000 per year, WorldCap has a significantly lower price tag.

*Disclosure: I have used Bloomberg and Reuters terminals in the past and I am affiliated with WorldCap.*

Comment: Mind telling us your association with WorldCap?